# Creating dynamically-typed tables using psycopg2's built-in formatting

Tags: python, sql, psycopg2

I'm working on a project in Python that interacts with a PostgreSQL data warehouse, and I'm using the psycopg2 API. I am looking to create dynamically-typed tables.

For example: I would like to be able to execute the following code:

```
from psycopg2 import connect, sql

connection = connect(host="host", port="port", database="database", user="user", password="pw")

def create_table(tbl_name, col_name, col_type):
    query = sql.SQL("CREATE TABLE {} ({} {})".format(sql.Identifier(tbl_name), sql.Identifier(col_name), sql.Identifier(column_type)))
    connection.execute(query)

create_table('animals', 'name', 'VARCHAR')
```

and end up with a table named "animals" that contains a column "name" of type VARCHAR. However, when I attempt to run this, I get an error: 'type "VARCHAR" does not exist'. I assume psycopg2's built-in formatter is putting double quotes around the VARCHAR type when there should not be any. Normally, I would just work around this myself, but the documentation is *very* clear that Python string concatenation should never be used for fear of SQL injection attacks. Security is a concern for this project, so I would like to know if it's possible to create dynamically-typed tables in this fashion using pyscopg2, and if not, whether there exists another third-party API that can do so securely. Thank you!

Danny

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga could you please elaborate? In the psycopg2 guide (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html), the following code (containing .format) is listed as proper use:

`cur.execute(SQL("INSERT INTO {} VALUES (%s)").format(Identifier('numbers')), (10,))`

Comment: You are correct

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, thanks for the clarification. Do you have any further insight into my original question? I'm really at a loss here and could use any ideas. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was also having so much trouble with this aspect. `sql.Identifier` is for double-quoted, well, SQL Identifiers which the datatypes (`INTEGER`, `TEXT`, etc.) are *not*. Looks like just making it plain SQL does the trick.

**N.B.** In your code, you should have pre-defined `columns` tuples and not expose their definition to the front-end. This is also why tuples are useful here as they are immutable.

```py
import psycopg2.sql as sql

def create_table( name, columns ):
    # name = "mytable"
    # columns = (("col1", "TEXT"), ("col2", "INTEGER"), ...)
    fields = []
    for col in columns:
        fields.append( sql.SQL( "{} {}" ).format( sql.Identifier( col[0] ), sql.SQL( col[1] ) ) )

    query = sql.SQL( "CREATE TABLE {tbl_name} ( {fields} );" ).format(
        tbl_name = sql.Identifier( name ),
        fields = sql.SQL( ', ' ).join( fields )
    )
    print( query.as_string(conn) ) # CREATE TABLE "mytable" ( "col1" TEXT, "col2" INTEGER );
    # Get cursor and execute...
```